# links opening in new window - Cheezy page-object ruby gem with selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, page-object-gem

I'm new to page-object and selenium, but so far it's all been going ok. The last elements I'm testing for this page are social media links.

To check that the links are correct i usually click them and then use selenium's driver.current_url to check that the url of the window is what we'd expect for that link, but these social media buttons are opening links in a new window (this is just to their static facebook page rather than a login etc) which causes the test to fail

is there a way of either:

1-forcing the link to open in the current window, or

2-extracting the target url from the link_element?

this is what the tests look like atm:

```
def test_facebook_button
assert @testpage.facebook_icon?, 'Facebook button not found'
@testpage.facebook_icon_link
sleep 5
assert @browser.current_url == '<facebookurlforsite>', 'Facebook link does not open expected URL'
end
```

if not i'm guessing i'd just use the actual selenium methods as some sort of exception to manually grab the properties of the link, i'd rather not some elements be in the page model and some out in the test itself but i can see how it's probably necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just checking that the link navigates to the right URL, checking the link's `href` attribute will be the quickest. The `PageObject::Elements::Link` elements have an [`href` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/page-object/PageObject/Platforms/SeleniumWebDriver/Link) for this.

Assuming that `facebook_icon_link` is your link defined by an accessor method, you would call:

```
facebook_icon_link_element.href
```

In other words, the assertion could be written as:

```
assert facebook_icon_link_element.href == '<facebookurlforsite>'
```